# jquery show/hide changes and change button font-awesome icon also

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

I have this piece of code:

https://jsfiddle.net/mhqrbsje/

html:

```
<button type="button" id="changesDisplay" class="btn btn-info btn-xs guideactions displayChanges">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>Show
</button>

<br>
    <br>
<p class="changec">This was changed</p>
<p class="changec">This was changed</p>
<p>Normal text</p>
```

css:

```
.changec
{
    display:none;    
}
```

js:

```
$('#changesDisplay').click(function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('h-changes')) {
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-th-large fa-th ');
            $('#changesDisplay').removeClass('h-changes');
            $('#changesDisplay').addClass('s-changes');

            $('.changec').show();

            $('.changec').css('color', 'red');
            $('.changec').css('font-style', 'italic');
            $('.changec').css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
        }
        else {
            $('#changesDisplay').addClass('h-changes');
            $('#changesDisplay').addClass('s-changes');
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-th-large fa-th');

            $('.changec').hide();

            $('.changec').css('color', '#000000');
            $('.changec').css('font-style', 'normal');
            $('.changec').css('text-decoration', 'none');

        }
});
```

that displays one button and when clicked it will show/hide the specific elements which are marked with a specific class (changes done). When the changes are shown, they are red, italic and stricked-through. Also the icon of the button changes when show/hide. In jsfiddle couldn't make it work with the font-awesome icons.

Basically the code works fine, but looks messy. Is there a way to rewrite it in a more elegant way having re-usability in mind?

Comment: It seems like your question does not match the topic; if you're specifically asking for a code clean-up, it would be appropriate to suggest that in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below code where I have relaced css style that you are removing / adding to `changec` with css clasess `h-changes` and `s-changes` with `display` attribute, so that you can just use `toggleClass` to achieve your functionality. -

HTML

```
<button type="button" id="changesDisplay" 
        class="btn btn-info btn-xs guideactions displayChanges">
     <i class="fa fa-th"></i>Show
</button>

<br>
    <br>
<p class="changec">This was changed</p>
<p class="changec">This was changed</p>
<p>Normal text</p>
```

CSS

```
.changec
{
    display:none; 
}

.h-changes
{
    color: red;
    font-style: italic;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    display: block;
}

.s-changes
{
    color: #000000;
    font-style: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery

```
$('.changec').addClass('s-changes');
$('#changesDisplay').click(function () {
        $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-th-large fa-th ');
        $('.changec').toggleClass('h-changes s-changes');
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mhqrbsje/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite your js like this

```
$('#changesDisplay').click(function () {

        if ($(this).hasClass('h-changes')) {
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-th-large fa-th ');
            $('#changesDisplay').removeClass('h-changes').addClass('s-changes');
            $('.changec').css('color', 'red').css('font-style', 'italic').css('text-decoration', 'line-through').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#changesDisplay').addClass('h-changes').addClass('s-changes');
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-th-large fa-th');
            $('.changec').css('color', '#000000').css('font-style', 'normal').css('text-decoration', 'none').hide();

        }
});
```

but the better way i think is add all css to separete classes in css file and manipulate with them.